# Reset Identity Value To 1 After Replication

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication, database-replication

I use SQL Server and I created a replication. Replication works very well. But i've create a backup subscriber's db to check values. I check tables with "IDENT_CURRENT" and i see  that identity column's values are 1. Is it normal? I can't a new insert to table because it's raise "Violation of PRIMARY KEY" error.
How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've write my own solution.
This code reset all table's identity values to max value.
I use it after database replication.

```
DECLARE @TableName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE emp_cursor CURSOR FOR     
select COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1
    order by TABLE_NAME    
  
OPEN emp_cursor   

FETCH NEXT FROM emp_cursor     
INTO @ColName,@TableName 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0    
BEGIN    
    --PRINT @ColName
    --PRINT @TableName
      
    

    DECLARE @MaxId  AS INT

    --PRINT @TableName
    EXEC ('DECLARE @MaxId  AS INT;
            DECLARE @TableName  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='''+@TableName+''';
            SELECT @MaxId=ISNULL(MAX(' + @ColName + '),0)+1 FROM '+@TableName+';'+
            'DBCC CHECKIDENT ('+@TableName+', RESEED,@MaxId);'+
            'PRINT ''Table: ''+ @TableName +'', New Identity Val:''+CAST(@MaxId AS NVARCHAR);PRINT CHAR(13);'
            
    )
```

FETCH NEXT FROM emp_cursor
INTO @ColName,@TableName

```
END     
CLOSE emp_cursor;    
DEALLOCATE emp_cursor;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reseed the identity value with [DBCC CHECKIDENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).  So discover the maximum value of the identity column in the table, and run something like:

eg

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Person.AddressType', RESEED, 10);  
GO
```